# Restoring the selection in an NSTableView (NSWindowRestoration)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nswindowrestoration

I'm working on window restoration in a non-document-based Cocoa app.  The app has a Mail.app-like interface. Each window represents an account; a sidebar in that window lists conversations in that account, and a main area lists messages in the selected conversation.

Each of these lists is a view-based `NSTableView`.  The conversation list is bound to an `NSArrayController` whose `contentSet` is bound to the window controller's `account` property; the message list is bound to a second `NSArrayController`, whose `contentSet` is bound to the first `NSArrayController`'s selection.

I've gotten my window restoration work to the point where it re-opens all the windows and re-associates them with the account objects, but I don't know how to restore the selections of the table views.  This doesn't seem to happen automatically—when the window is restored, an object is selected, but it's not the one that was previously selected.  What's going on here?  What will be the easiest approach to saving and restoring the selection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you realized, `NSTableView` doesn't auto save the selection.

The easiest way is to bind your `NSTableView`'s `selectionIndexes` to your `Array Controller`'s `selectionIndexes`, and save/retrieve values from `NSUserDefaults`. Then you can bind the array controller's `selectionIndexes` to the `Shared User Defaults Controller` (with Controller Key `values` and you can name your `Model Key Path` anything). Because `NSIndexSet` needs to be archived/unarchived to be stored, use the `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` value transformer. That, in itself, should work.

---

If you had trouble like I did with the selection indexes resetting because the table view wasn't immediately repopulated (I doubt you'd have these problems, because you're populating with bindings), you can save defaults manually.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.arrayController.selectionIndexes] valueForKey:vvLastSavedSelectionIndex];
```

And retrieve them:

```
NSIndexSet *selectionIndexes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:vvLastSavedSelectionIndex]];
[self.arrayController setSelectionIndexes:selectionIndexes];
```

Comment: Since I can have multiple windows and I'm already using `NSWindowRestoration`, I encoded them into the window's restorable state using the `-window:willEncodeRestorableState:` and `-window:didDecodeRestorableState:` delegate methods, but that was definitely a good approach. Thanks!

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon That definitely sounds alot smoother than writing to `NSUserDefaults` in the case of multiple windows (and even one window), thanks for letting me know about your method!

Comment: Somehow, when I do exactly that (EVEN with the code, but I have bindings), the TableView is instantly empty :( I'm talking about Vervious' idea, because my app isn't Document-based. Any idea?