# Restoring Core Data Master-Detail selections across runs

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings, master-detail

I'm trying to make a row selection in an `NSTableView` persist across app runs.

I have an `NSTableView` that acts as a Master view, and an `NSCollectionView` for the detail view.  My sample project is here:
http://www.filesend.net/download.php?f=3f34594d71e32b2c1fbef768eccb56b0

These two views are bound appropriately to `NSArrayControllers` with Cocoa bindings.  These are, in turn, bound to a Master Entity, a Detail Entity and a one-to-many relationship “myChildren” in a CoreData store.  The “myDetailAC” Content Set is bound to the CD relationship.  In my App Delegate, I create some sample data in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` callback.

This all works swimmingly well once the app is up and running… selecting rows of the Table causes the detail `NSCollectionView` to show the details for the master item.  In fact, what I've built serves as a good starting example for Master-Detail setup using Core Data and Cocoa bindings.

The problem is this: when I quit the app and restart it, I would like the TableView row to be selected with the most recent master selection (and automatically the appropriate detail data set).

One of my attributes in my CD Master entity is `isSelected`, which is set based on which row of the `NSTableView` was last selected.

I have attempted to override `NSArrayController` in “MasterAC.m" for the master table.  In here, I've attempted to call `setSelectionIndexes` from within it to alter array controller's selection based on the `isSelected` flag.  I do so from within the array controller's `arrangeObjects` method.

No dice.

**Can anyone help out with persisting the Table Selection across runs of the sample app?**

In short, if I quit the app with “Parent #3” selected, then running the app again will cause “parent #3” to be selected along with its detail info.

Some other suggestions on SO deal with this using NSUserDefaults, but not Core Data.
[Restoring the selection in an NSTableView (NSWindowRestoration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861693/restoring-the-selection-in-an-nstableview-nswindowrestoration)

Answer (score 0):

What might be the easiest solution, if you’re targeting newer OSes, is just to use "state restoration." It’ll reach into the master table and essentially re-click the selection for you, and it even scrolls to the right point. It’s kind of magical when it works.